# How to print a row wise sorted matrix in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am given a 2D array of numbers whose each row is sorted individually. I need to print the whole matrix in sorted order(ascending). Can anyone tell how to do it efficiently and its time complexity. If you can code,please paste your C++ code.

Comment: Some clarification neccessary: Each row is already sorted? And what do you mean by printing the matrix in sorted order? Do you want to sort the rows in some order or the whole matrix? An example would help.

Comment: Each row is sorted means that like if I have a 2D Matrix of size 2x5 ad the first row is :{2,8,14,34,134} and the second row is {3,5,23,45,89} then I need to print it as :2 3 5 8 14 23 34 45 89 134,generalize it for mxn matrix

Comment: Basically what you need to do is the merge step of merge sort then:
http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/mergeSort.htm

Answer (score 0):

This code might help!

```
unsigned char arr[columnsize][rowsize];

unsigned char out[columnsize*rowsize];

for(unsigned int i=0; i<columnsize*rowsize; i++){
    char buffer=1;
    bool brk=false;
    for(unsigned int y=0; y<rowsize; y++){
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<columnsize; x++){
            if(arr[x][y] <= buffer){
                buffer = arr[x][y];
                arr[x][y] = 0;
                brk = true;
            }
            if(brk) break;
        }
        if(brk) break;
    }
    out[i] = buffer;
}
```

Comment: This is quadratic in the number of elements in the matrix while the merge sort merge step is linear in the number of elements.

Comment: This is a little less complicated and easier to understand from my point of view. There are some performance flaws but still gives the result wanted

Comment: It is easier to understand, but he is also asking for complexity and an efficient way to do it.